# PHP serialize, array structure

Tags: php, json, serialization

Im having issues serializing some JSON into the format I require, to store in a DB.

I want a structure like (so no key):

```
a:10:{s:8:"location";s:5:"London";s:6:"_token";s:40:"5969e8f11f20b12afc6dfc7b9ce4a6acfc44544d";s:8:"producttype";s:6:"rental";}
```

But when I do:

```
$array[] = $postData['queryData'];
$parameters = serialize($array);
```

I get an array with key:

```
a:1:{i:0;s:321:"{"location":"London","_token":"140e8a2f50db0e62f42cfd27662b3b746aa7bf22","producttype":"rental"}
```

and if I do:

```
  $parameters = serialize($postData['queryData']);
```

I get just a string:

```
s:321:"{"location":"London","_token":"f7aad7cc4d1e1f8b999970c820001a17a3e6cfee","saletype":"rental"};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$postData['queryData']` apparently is a JSON string. You're serialising a PHP string which contains JSON data. If you want to serialise a PHP array structure, you'll have to decode the JSON string into a PHP array before serialising it:

```
serialize(json_decode($postData['queryData'], true))
```